# How to type frameshift-operator | Custom vector operator

Tags: arrows, superscripts, vector

I have to use this frameshift-operator, but I could not find a way to reproduce it. I've only found `\vec{}` and the `\vv` command from the `esvect`-package, but the index is at the wrong side of the arrow when using these commands. Does anyone have an idea?

[image: Frameshft-operator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\overset` with a twist:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\timeshift}[1]{%
  \overset{\scriptscriptstyle t\to}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

$\timeshift{\mathbf{H}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]